# Disable TAX on a specific shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address, table-rates

Hi we are using Webshopapps Premium Rates for shipping options, the issue we are having is that all shipping methods at the moment have TAX added by Magento on top of what we set.

Some options we have in there we don't want tax adding onto! How can I disable tax for a specific method and not all?

has anyone come across this problem? Is there something I can do on the cart page to check what shipping method has been used a remove VAT before checkout?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of that option - shipping method (or carrier) specific taxes. Though Webshopapps does have shipping tax changing extension, from its description it does not sound like it suits your particular needs.

However, if it is not too much trouble shopping cart rules may help. You set up rules that if shipping method is this, shipping country is that, give discount of exactly the tax amount.

Another option is to have shipping prices without tax completely and only use Webshopapps Premium Rates - setting specific fees for all destinations and the price then as including or excluding tax based on your wishes. Given that this is possible with the extension (as I do not have it) and that is the only shipping carrier you use.

Otherwise you would probably need to override *Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Tax*.